# how to Upload Photo in twitter from android

Tags: android

I have tried upload a photo in twitter but the status is send not photo.  Can anyone suggest some help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tries this far? Are you using an API?

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381671/is-there-any-twitter-demo-exmaple-to-post-photo-on-twitter-with-using-oauth-in-t

Answer (score 2):

You need to upload the picture to a picture service like twitpic, which will return an URL, that you then put into your status update.

There are libraries like [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/) out there, that can help you with this task.

Have a look at [Zwitscher](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA) on how to use it: [code to upload](https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/TwitterHelper.java#L860)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code..

```
    final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "") != null ? prefs
                        .getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "") : "";
                String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "") != null ? prefs
                        .getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "") : "";


                    if (token != null && !token.trim().equals("") && secret != null
                        && !secret.trim().equals("")) {
                    AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token, secret);
                    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY,
                            Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

     Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()                 
                        .setOAuthConsumerKey(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY) 
                        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET) 
                        .setOAuthAccessToken(a.getToken()) 
                        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(a.getTokenSecret()) 
                        .build(); 

     OAuthAuthorization auth = new OAuthAuthorization (conf, conf.getOAuthConsumerKey (), conf.getOAuthConsumerSecret (), new AccessToken (conf.getOAuthAccessToken (), AuthAccessTokenSecret ()));

       ImageUpload upload = ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader ("fa6707f43c41faab003dc134348acabd",auth);

        url = upload.upload(new File(path));


        twitter.updateStatus(url);


///Add twitter4j-core-2.1.11jar to libs
```

Comment: After uploading to twitpic a url will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter4j 3.0.3 has updated its `ImageUpload` class. `ImageUpload.getTwitpicUploader` method is now deprecated; it has only `ImageUpload.upload` method. Also, you have to add these two .jar on your projects build path:

- twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar
- twitter4j-media-support-3.0.3.jar

You can get more info at: http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/3.0.3/index.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an app on twitter

here is code to post message on twitter

```
 ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_key));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(context.getResources().getString(R.string.twitter_consumer_secret));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(LoginActivity.getAccessToken((context)));
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(LoginActivity.getAccessTokenSecret(context));
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        final Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                private double x;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                        boolean success = true;
                        try {
                                x = Math.random();
                                twitter.updateStatus(message +" "+x);
                        } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                success = false;
                        }

                        final boolean finalSuccess = success;

                        callingActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                        postResponse.onFinsihed(finalSuccess);
                                }
                        });

                }
        }).start();
```

check this [tutorial](http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/tutorial-on-uploading-image-on-twitter-using-twitter4j/) for more details.