# is there any twitter demo example to post photo on twitter with using OAuth in twitter?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, android-twitter

I want to upload the Photo on Twitter as like ttweet photo.
by Searching on net I got Some Example of the twiiter4j example to tweet the Photo on twitter. but in that example demo I have to enter the static Username and Password to post.
I want is to enter and managed the username and password by twitter OAuth and post the photo on twitter...
So is there any Demo that can Post the Photo on Twitter using Twitter OAuth?

Comment: Twitter API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media

Comment: @Blender: thanks for the reply. But i want any demo example that do like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitpic is the place where your photos(tweeted on Twitter) are hosted. So once you get the username password for twitpic,you can upload photo to it using below code sample project. It would just upload the photo and gives you the link.so finally you will have to code for posting that link onto twitter as tweet.

Here is the complete project sample: https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidTwitpic

Comment: Realy Nice Example that i want. But while i am going to exit from that account and then again login to the twitter, I seems nothing.

Comment: You mean,you don't see the tweet you have sent with the image link you got from this example app? or something else?

Comment: Yes i dont get tweet. But while i go to twitPic site i show me the Picture i have uploaded. And While i am going to use this example second time i am not able to post the image. why ?

Comment: Hmm...I too get nothing on screen for signing in again into twitter once logged out. Else I am able to send as many image as i want through the app once i am signed in. there is no problem at all.

Comment: Yes, Application works fine but if user get signout from there the there is nothing disply in twitter dialog.

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for the help. realy a Nice Example. and yes with this example you can not able to see the currently uploaded photo in tweet but you can see it on tweetPic. I have one exmple where you can see the currently uploade photo on both twitter and on tweetPic.

Comment: can you give its reference link here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5585/discussion-between-idroid-explorer-and-hiral)

Comment: I downloded this sample and imported in eclipse but i am getting error in TwitterApp class at line mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken); So please help me any one,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you need demo's just do  a search on Github. You will be able to see a lot of demo applications from others.

[Twitter4j-android-Sample](https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample)

[twitterdroid](https://github.com/fbrunel/twitterdroid)

[Tweety](https://github.com/fmaker/Tweety)

[TweetView](https://github.com/cacois/TweetView)

Or maybe this [list](https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Java&q=twitter&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories&x=23&y=12) will have something for you.

Comment: My Question is about to post the image on twitter. Even with this example i am not able to post the status on twitter.

Comment: If you have any demo example that post image on the twitter with custom text then let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @blessenm  recetly none of above demo working can you help me.