# To post a photo in Twitter in android in a button click ?

Tags: android

In my app i want to post a photo in twitter in a button click.
so i uses so many code but does not work.
so i want to get the code to share a photo in twitter in one click

Answer (score 2):

Before going to ask question. Try to google or search on SO for the similar questions.

See here:[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381671/is-there-any-twitter-demo-exmaple-to-post-photo-on-twitter-with-using-oauth-in-t)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
                targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     "My body of post/email");
                targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );

                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShare, "Select app to share");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShare);
                startActivity(chooserIntent);
```